# Print a pdf file from a large pdf file

Tags: printing, pdf, virtual-printer

I'm trying to print, in a pdf file, just one page from another large pdf file. Does anyone have a clue? I'm using foxit reader, and when I try ctrl+P appears just the installed printers as an option to print. There is no print to file button like in other programs such as libreoffice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `printer-driver-cups-pdf` - this program creates a system pdf printer for you.

`sudo apt install printer-driver-cups-pdf`

will install and enable the printer.

The output from the printer by default, will appear in your home_directory/PDF (`~/PDF`)

Comment: Won't that already be installed though? The OP states that (emphasis mine) "There is no print to file button _like in other programs such as libreoffice_". If the other tools have the print to PDF option, then this package is already installed, right?

Comment: @terdon I think libreoffice has a direct "save as PDF", and I'm not entirely sure that it would do a single page, as opposed to the cups-pdf option with allows for a pretty full range of print functions, like print page 5 of 8.

Comment: It does, but that is separate from the print dialog. I get the impression from the OP that the print to file works everywhere except foxit reader. Which seems odd.

Comment: @terdon Foxit is a funny kindof a program - I have used it in the past, but have not found enough benefits to continue to use it.

Comment: @Nelson_nags13 If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I stand corrected!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative would be to extract the required page with pdftk. E.g to extract page 10 of infile.pdf and save it as outfile.pdf:

```
pdftk infile.pdf cat 10 output outfile.pdf
```