# How to use CUPS PDF to create a network PDF printer

Tags: networking, printing, pdf, cups-lpd

I'm using https://github.com/hanazuki/docker-ubuntu-cups to run cups PDF on an ubuntu docker. I mapped like this:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 6310:631 -e ADMIN_USERNAME=admin -e CUPS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin -v $HOME/cups:/var/spool/cups-pdf/ANONYMOUS cups
```

so my `6130` port is `613` inside cups. I can access the web admin panel. However, I tried adding several printer types from this list:

```
Add Printer
Local Printers:     CUPS-BRF (Virtual Braille BRF Printer)
CUPS-PDF (Virtual PDF Printer)
Discovered Network Printers:    
Other Network Printers:     Backend Error Handler
Internet Printing Protocol (https)
AppSocket/HP JetDirect
Internet Printing Protocol (ipps)
Internet Printing Protocol (ipp)
Internet Printing Protocol (http)
LPD/LPR Host or Printer
```

but none of them appears in my firefox (which is in the same machine) when I try to print something. I checked "share printer" in all of them.

How do I make a printer appear at firefox so I can print and get a PDF from it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/a/1134447/307670

Comment: @Graham this looks like a local printer, not a network shared one. Or did I understand it wrong?

Comment: I use it in a local network environment of 2 Ubuntu PCs and PDF shows as a printer in both from FF